# Issue num_tokens on cassandra after perform a node restore - Cassandra 3.11.10 and 3.11.11

Tags: cassandra, cassandra-3.0

After upgrading from 3.0.13 to 3.11.10 I'm having issue when I retsore the data from the node. After the restore is done it changes the number of tokens from 256 to 512.In cassandra.yaml it still num_token: 256, so I have no idea what's going on here.

These are the steps I'm performing

```
rm -rf /var/lib/cassandra/data/*
rm -rf /var/lib/cassandra/commitlog/*
rm -rf /var/lib/cassandra/saved_caches/*
rm -rf /var/lib/cassandra/hints/*
rm -rf /var/log/cassandra/*
tar -xvf $BACKUP_LOC/$BACKUP_NAME.tar -C /
find ${DATA_DIR} -mindepth 2 -path "*/snapshots/${BACKUP_NAME}/*" -type f \-exec bash -c 'dir={} && cd ${dir%/*} && mv {} ../..' \;

nodetool -u $NODETOOL_USR -pw $NODETOOL_PASSWD -h $(hostname) refresh $keyspace $table --ssl" >>$BACKUP_LOC/nodetool_refresh_commands.sh
```

When I restart the node after perfoming the steps above it changes the tokens from 256 to 512.

ERROR:

> ERROR [main] 2021-10-07 15:16:24,060 CassandraDaemon.java:803 - Fatal configuration error
> org.apache.cassandra.exceptions.ConfigurationException: Cannot change the number of tokens from 512 to 256
> at org.apache.cassandra.service.StorageService.joinTokenRing(StorageService.java:1102) ~[apache-cassandra-3.11.11.jar:3.11.11]
> at org.apache.cassandra.service.StorageService.initServer(StorageService.java:760) ~[apache-cassandra-3.11.11.jar:3.11.11]
> at org.apache.cassandra.service.StorageService.initServer(StorageService.java:694) ~[apache-cassandra-3.11.11.jar:3.11.11]
> at org.apache.cassandra.service.CassandraDaemon.setup(CassandraDaemon.java:395) [apache-cassandra-3.11.11.jar:3.11.11]
> at org.apache.cassandra.service.CassandraDaemon.activate(CassandraDaemon.java:633) [apache-cassandra-3.11.11.jar:3.11.11]
> at org.apache.cassandra.service.CassandraDaemon.main(CassandraDaemon.java:786) [apache-cassandra-3.11.11.jar:3.11.11]
> INFO  [StorageServiceShutdownHook] 2021-10-07 15:16:24,064 HintsService.java:209 - Paused hints dispatch
> INFO  [StorageServiceShutdownHook] 2021-10-07 15:16:24,064 Gossiper.java:1683 - Announcing shutdown

Any ideas on it?
Thanks,

Answer (score 2):

The problem here is that you've deleted all the contents of the `data/` directory including the system keyspaces/tables:

```
rm -rf /var/lib/cassandra/data/*
```

You shouldn't restore system tables from backups -- you should only ever restore application keyspaces/tables.

The most likely cause of this exception:

```
ERROR [main] 2021-10-07 15:16:24,060 CassandraDaemon.java:803 - \
  Fatal configuration error org.apache.cassandra.exceptions.ConfigurationException: \
  Cannot change the number of tokens from 512 to 256
```

is that the `system.local` table got corrupted.

If you try to dump the contents of one of the SSTables for `system.local`, you'll see that it will contain 512 tokens. For example:

```
$ sstabledump me-1234-big-Data.db
...
          { "name" : "tokens", "path" : [ "-1090765148586270517" ], "value" : "", "tstamp" : "2021-10-12T01:23:45.678Z" },
          { "name" : "tokens", "path" : [ "-1118040538640756774" ], "value" : "", "tstamp" : "2021-10-12T01:23:45.678Z" },
          { "name" : "tokens", "path" : [ "-1256255083036528868" ], "value" : "", "tstamp" : "2021-10-12T01:23:45.678Z" },
...
```

```
$ sstabledump me-1234-big-Data.db | grep -c tokens
512
```

There is no workaround available once the `system.local` table gets corrupted. The only solution is to completely wipe all the C* directories and re-bootstrap the node. Cheers!